# Splide Slider and NVDA 2023.1 focus issue for previous and next button

Tags: firefox, accessibility, nvda, wcag2.0, splidejs

When we click on next or previous arrows button the focus is shifting to pagination dots which is wrong and this issue is observed in NVDA 2023.1 and splide js library
https://splidejs.com/

In NVDA screen reader when we click on previous/Next the focus need to on respective arrow button and need to announce the slider change

Comment: I just tried the "Default" example on the splidejs page you had linked to and it worked great with NVDA. I tabbed to the next button, pressed enter a few times and the slide advanced without moving the keyboard focus.